# Please help me check my codes. how can i get the filled forms in my mail

Tags: html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
<input id="sendto" name="sendto" type="hidden"        action="mailto:admin@vervemycashlesscampus.com" />
</div>
```

how can the answers be sent to my mail pls? Check if i wrote d code properly

Comment: Please provide any code showing what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your `mailto:` link in your `form`'s `action` attribute.

```
<form action="mailto:admin@vervemycashlesscampus.com" method="post">
```